# Why does this behaviour with nodejs and child process happen?

Tags: node.js, process

**What am I trying to do?**
I want to clone multiple git repositories from nodejs.

**How do I achieve that?**
First I have this method in a separate file:

```js
const exec = require("child_process").exec;
const { printError } = require("./printers");

function execute(command) {
  console.log(`Running command: ${command}`);
  let result = "";
  let savedError = undefined;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const proc = exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      savedError = savedError || stderr || error;
      result += stdout;
    });

    proc.on("close", (code) => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        console.error(
          [
            "================================================================",
            `Command ${command} failed.`,
            `Status code: ${code}`,
            `Error message: ${savedError}`,
            `Output: ${result}`,
            "================================================================",
            "",
          ].join("\n")
        );
        reject(result);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
```

Then I use it in my main module (code is abbreviated and bit simplified just so you can get the point:

```js
const repoUrls = ["url1", "url2"]; // imagine these are real urls

async function main() {
  const copyOfUrls = [...repoUrls];

  while (copyOfUrls.length) {
    try {
      await execute(
        `git clone ${copyOfUrls[0]} repositories/${repoUrlFileFriendly(
          copyOfUrls[0]
        )}`
      );
  
      console.log('fun fact - this console log never happens');
      copyOfUrls.shift()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to clone, see error:", error);
    }
  }
}
```

**What is the problem?**
Well, code works BUT after cloning first repo, the process exits (both the child process and the main one) and second repository is never even attempted to be cloned. (note the "console.log('fun fact - this console log never happens');").

Comment: I tried running your code locally (adding real URLs, substituting the repoUrlFIleFirendly function, etc), and it appears to run just fine, cloning 2 repos and then stopping. When the process exits, does it log anything at all?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time, there was no any log or anything, I did not change anything now, after shutdown the PC and taking a nap I've tried again and seems like restart fixed issues...interesting.